# Adding directories to SVN

Tags: perl, svn, tortoisesvn, perl-module

I am trying to create Perl script to automatically create folders and checkout a project with SVN Tortoise.

I started with a function that checks if all specified directories exist. If a directory does not exist, it gets created by this function.

This works fine. Now I would like "add" these created folders to the SVN.

How can I add these folders to the SVN?

Comment: Why are you trying to automate TortoiseSVN when CPAN has the [`SVN::Client`](http://search.cpan.org/~mlanier/Alien-SVN-1.6.12.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) module?

Answer (score 1):

To add directory into `SVN` you should use `svn add` command. If your directories you have created are stored at `@dirs` you may try to do this:

```
`svn add "$_"` for @dirs
```

Then you should commit your changes

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise SVN is automatable. I would recommend you to follow the official automation guide provided at https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

You can use the `:add` to add files to version control.

---

Have a look at [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) if you are not restricted to using Tortoise SVN.